# Focus lost after ajax update on iOS with VoiceOver active

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, accessibility, wcag2.0

I have a filter which loads as an overlay on mobile devices and uses AJAX to update the content on body of page.

The modal is closed and I am placing focus on empty DIV and then move it to an element inside new content.  The result on Android devices with TalkBack running is working as expected; however, in iOS with VoiceOver the JavaScript executes the function and then some other event fires and places focus on the body.

There is documentation about this issue occurring on iOS devices when AJAX is involved and the solution I attempted is recommended as success criteria in WCAG 2.0.  Is there any other solution which has proven successful for others?

```
function accessibilityFocus(){
$('.accessibility-actions').focus();
setTimeout(function () {
$('.multiselect-sort-message').attr('tabindex', '-1').focus();
}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: How is `.multiselect-sort-message` generated is it dynamically? I just tested this https://jsfiddle.net/f6st9enL/ quickly on iPhone and it works fine. http://imgshr.com/06c283811e

Comment: Yes, it is returned in an HTML fragment that loads with the new content.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the element isn't actually there yet, but hard to confirm without the actual code.

Comment: The AJAX actually performs the request and replacement of the data as soon as a filter is selected.  The focus function I added fires when the click event to close the modal occurs.